# c3p0 A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool

Tags: mysql, tomcat, database-connection, c3p0

I have a java application deployed on tomcat version 7. For the data source I used c3p0 which connects to a mysql database.
It was working fine for years and recently I started to get this error : 
"A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool".

When I have this issue the only solution is restarting the application. Restarting mysql doesn't help.

I have also php applications using the save database and they are not affected, they work properly.

I java application is used only by a small team, it's a backend application.

Here is my c3p0 configuration :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
  <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?relaxAutoCommit=true&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;autoReconnectForPools=true" />
  <property name="user" value="viva4578" />
  <property name="password" value="amd139fbg" />
  <property name="initialPoolSize" value="5" />
  <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
  <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="14400" />
  <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="30000" />
  <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1" />
  <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="30" />
  <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true" />
  <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" />
  <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
  <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="3600" />
  <property name="maxIdleTime" value="7200" />
  <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="1800" />
  <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="3600" />
  <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Here is the output log of c3p0 after starting the application :

```
Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ 
  acquireIncrement -> 1,
  acquireRetryAttempts -> 30,
  acquireRetryDelay -> 1000,
  autoCommitOnClose -> false,
  userOverrides -> {},
  automaticTestTable -> null,
  breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false,
  checkoutTimeout -> 30000,
  connectionCustomizerClassName -> null,
  connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester,
  contextClassLoaderSource -> caller,
  dataSourceName -> z8kflt9n1b12nsh118544e|7bc1a68b,
  debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> true,
  description -> null,
  driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver,
  extensions -> {},
  factoryClassLocation -> null,
  forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false,
  forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false,
  identityToken -> z8kflt9n1b12nsh118544e|7bc1a68b,
  idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 3600,
  initialPoolSize -> 5,
  jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?relaxAutoCommit=true&autoReconnect=true&autoReconnectForPools=true,
  maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0,
  maxConnectionAge -> 14400,
  maxIdleTime -> 7200,
  maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 1800,
  maxPoolSize -> 20,
  maxStatements -> 0,
  maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0,
  minPoolSize -> 5,
  numHelperThreads -> 3,
  preferredTestQuery -> SELECT 1,
  privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false,
  properties -> {user=******, password=******},
  propertyCycle -> 0,
  statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0,
  testConnectionOnCheckin -> true,
  testConnectionOnCheckout -> true,
  unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 3600,
  usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false
]
```

I am using the version 0-0.9.5 of c3p0.

If someone can help

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Here

```
<property name="checkoutTimeout" value="30000" />
```

You have configured c3p0 to throw this Exception if a client can't get served within 30 seconds. That's started to happen. Presumably the load on the `DataSource` has increased. Consider scaling it up. Make `maxPoolSize` bigger, and increase `numHelperThreads` as well, in case the issue is a backlog in asynchronous tasks.

(You can also increase the value of `checkoutTimeout`, or remove the setting, so that client checkouts never time out. That would eliminate this Exception. But not really the problem. 30 seconds is a long time to wait for a Connection. It's probably better to tune c3p0 to provide Connections a lot more promptly than that.)

Comment: OK thank you for your input. I my opinion 30 seconds is a lot except if there is a slow query.

Comment: I changed a the log4j config and now I see this exception

Comment: A checked-out resource is overdue, and will be destroyed: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection

Maybe this is the root cause of the problem ?

Comment: yes. that means you have a Connection leak, and an `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` of an hour (3600 secs) means that you are very likely to run out of Connections before c3p0 cleans the leaked Connections up for you. I see that you have `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTrace`, which means you should see a stack trace of the codepath that checked out the never-closed Connection, You should make your `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` much shorter (something like 30 secs is typical), and look at the logged stack traces to determine what code path is leaking Connection. Fix that and you may fix everything

Comment: Yes I have the stack trace and I see that the issue comes from one method. I will check that and let you know thank you !!!

Comment: Hello, I changed unreturnedConnectionTimeout to 120 sec and this solved the problem because I don't have too many concurrent users. But to eliminate the problem completely (no more connection leak) I made the method that causing the issue transactional.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I recent got the same error message when I setting `maxPoolSize=0`. Anyone who is facing this problem can consider my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a transaction configuration issue. I had in a service, a method which wasn't marked with the annotation @Transaction